# Insert HTML in PowerPoint document with a content add-in

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I am looking to develop an Office content add-in for PowerPoint. The purpose of this add-in is to embed HTML(an iframe) into a slide. Something similar to [Web Video Player](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104221182&sourcecorrid=223d12b0-9e50-42e2-9161-933afef81d73&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false).

Looking at the docs, the way you would implement this is via [Document.setSelectedDataAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.setselecteddataasync), however the HTML coercion type is not supported in PowerPoint.

Is there another way to insert/embed HTML content into PowerPoint, seeing as the add-in linked above is able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web video player shows the HTML directly in the content pane for the add-in instead of inserting it into the document. For example, you could use something like:

```
document.body.innerHTML = myCustomSlideHTML;
```

-Michael (developer of Web Video Player)